# npm streaming-s3, streaming an image from request.get()

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, stream

I am testing the [streaming-s3 package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streaming-s3), and trying to get the basic tutorial to upload from a request.get to work.

At the moment, it stays stuck and never starts, crashes, or anything...

My code :

```
var elem = list.shift();
  console.log(elem._id+" "+elem.main_img); //elem contains exactly what it should
  var rStream = request.get(elem.main_img);
  uploader = new StreamingS3(rStream, {accessKeyId:'XXXXXX', secretAccessKey:'XXXXXXX',region:"eu-west-1"},
    {
      Bucket: 'xxxxxx-myimages',
      Key: elem._id,
      ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
      ACL:'public-read'
    },
    {
      concurrentParts: 2,
      waitTime: 10000,
      retries: 1,
      maxPartSize: 10*1024*1024,
    }
  );

  uploader.begin(); // important if callback not provided.

  uploader.on('data', function (bytesRead) {
    console.log(bytesRead, ' bytes read.');
  }).on('part', function (number) {
    console.log('Part ', number, ' uploaded.');
  }).on('uploaded', function (stats) {
    console.log('Upload stats: ', stats);
  }).on('finished', function (resp, stats) {
    console.log('Upload finished: ', resp);
  }).on('error', function (e) {
    console.log('Upload error: ', e);
  });
```

It's basically a copypaste with the blanks filled in... What could cause it not to work AND not to display any output? I checked the request and it replies with a 200 statusCode. Console.log the uploader shows everything filled properly...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure everything is set in that list? Here's my console output for the [file I've just uploaded](https://s3.amazonaws.com/zlatko-test/123):

```
node temp
123 http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3c6263c3453b
16902 ' bytes read.'
2543 ' bytes read.'
Part  1  uploaded.
Upload stats:  { downloadSpeed: Infinity,
  uploadSpeed: 9722500,
  downloadTime: 0,
  uploadTime: 2,
  size: 19445 }
Upload finished:  { Location: 'https://zlatko-test.s3.amazonaws.com/123',
  Bucket: 'zlatko-test',
  Key: '123',
  ETag: '"de7139567df95ed9dacadfc5a3a1317c-1"' }
```

And here's how I've modified your file, basically adding a static element and changing the access info to be taken from my shell:

```
var list = [{main_img: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3c6263c3453b', _id: '123'}];

var request = require('request');
var StreamingS3 = require('streaming-s3');
var elem = list.shift();
console.log(elem._id+" "+elem.main_img); //elem contains exactly what it should
var rStream = request.get(elem.main_img);
uploader = new StreamingS3(rStream, {accessKeyId:process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY, secretAccessKey:process.env.S3_SECRET,region:process.env.S3_REGION},
    {
        Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
        Key: elem._id,
        ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
        ACL:'public-read'
    },
    {
        concurrentParts: 2,
        waitTime: 10000,
        retries: 1,
        maxPartSize: 10*1024*1024,
    }
);

uploader.begin(); // important if callback not provided.

uploader.on('data', function (bytesRead) {
    console.log(bytesRead, ' bytes read.');
}).on('part', function (number) {
    console.log('Part ', number, ' uploaded.');
}).on('uploaded', function (stats) {
    console.log('Upload stats: ', stats);
}).on('finished', function (resp, stats) {
    console.log('Upload finished: ', resp);
}).on('error', function (e) {
    console.log('Upload error: ', e);
});
```

You on windows or something?

Comment: nope, Unix... strange, I had a similar problem with knox S3 library, and both vanished when I used the http module instead of request... http.get streams to s3, not request.get.

Comment: What version of request?

Comment: hmm, I've got the latest from npm.
Does my modified program work with you? Maybe try, then change line by line to see where it breaks. Setup ENV vars first, like `S3_BUCKET=mybucket S3_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxxxx S3_SECRET=xxxxxxx S3_REGION=us-east-1 node script.js`